# How to implement "equals" for interface from mongodb?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, interface

```
export interface IHealthPlanCard {
    _id: string,
    statusId: string;
}

const cards: IHealthPlanCard[] = await healthPlanCardsCollection.find(...)
cards.filter(card => card.statusId.equals(cardStatusId))
```

In that case it shows me error: *Property **'equals'** does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)*

I **can't** write something like that:

```
export interface IHealthPlanCard {
    _id: string,
    statusId: string | eqauls;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB (or mongoose) and dealing with ObjectIds, you should always use the `ObjectId` type instead of `string`:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb"
// import { Types } from "mongoose"

export interface IHealthPlanCard {
  _id: string,
  statusId: ObjectId;
}

const cards: IHealthPlanCard[] = await healthPlanCardsCollection.find(...)
cards.filter(card => card.statusId.equals(cardStatusId))
```

This will **only** work if you defined your schema to use `ObjectId` instead of `string`.

Now your ObjectIds will have the `.equals()` method.

Comment: Ah, okay. import { ObjectId } from "mongodb"
I used this one and selected statusId: ObjectId in interface, no error now. Need only to test it :)
Thank you!